# Situation using guice + requestfactory in maven-gae-gwt project

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, maven, guice, requestfactory

I'm trying to set my develop enviroment and I got a big problem.
I'm setting it to run a gwt-gae-maven app which will use guice for dependency injection and requestfactory to persist data.
I used an api that I found here https://github.com/etiennep/injected-requestfactory... which looks magic but dont works for me. Tryed to do like here http://www.wanderingcanadian.ca/guiced-up-gwt-requestfactory and nothing works...
When I try to run it as webapplication I got this exception and nothing works:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryModule.getValidatorFactory(InjectedRequestFactoryModule.java:42)
  while locating javax.validation.ValidatorFactory
  at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryModule.getValidator(InjectedRequestFactoryModule.java:59)
  while locating javax.validation.Validator
    for parameter 1 at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedServiceLayerDecorator.<init>(InjectedServiceLayerDecorator.java:36)
  while locating com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedServiceLayerDecorator
  while locating com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator
    for parameter 1 at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryServlet.<init>(InjectedRequestFactoryServlet.java:25)
  while locating com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryServlet

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:741)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:763)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:74)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:168)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:593)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:785)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:732)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:785)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:728)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:785)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:51)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:785)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:732)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:778)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:728)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:101)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload$WebAppClassLoaderExtension.findClass(JettyLauncher.java:372)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:366)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
    at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryModule.getValidatorFactory(InjectedRequestFactoryModule.java:42)
    ... 64 more
   [WARN] Failed startup of context com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload@7c125c9e{/,C:\Rodrigo\Desenvolvimento\Glazier\glazier\src\main\webapp}
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryModule.getValidatorFactory(InjectedRequestFactoryModule.java:42)
  while locating javax.validation.ValidatorFactory
  at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryModule.getValidator(InjectedRequestFactoryModule.java:59)
  while locating javax.validation.Validator
    for parameter 1 at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedServiceLayerDecorator.<init>(InjectedServiceLayerDecorator.java:36)
  while locating com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedServiceLayerDecorator
  while locating com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator
    for parameter 1 at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryServlet.<init>(InjectedRequestFactoryServlet.java:25)
  while locating com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryServlet

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:741)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:763)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:74)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:168)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:593)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:785)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:732)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:785)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:728)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:785)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:51)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:785)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:732)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:778)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:728)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:101)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload$WebAppClassLoaderExtension.findClass(JettyLauncher.java:372)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:366)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
    at com.kradcifer.glazier.server.requestfactory.InjectedRequestFactoryModule.getValidatorFactory(InjectedRequestFactoryModule.java:42)
    ... 64 more
```

Also I tryed to run it without guice, specifying the servlet directly on web.xml, but got the same error (but this time not when I run the application, but when I start it).

Tryed a lot of things and nothing worked... always the same error. I think it's probly just a detail that I can't see... I can't continue till I fix it... someone knows how to?

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't solve it... my way to fix it was deleting the project and starting it again... and now it works, don't know what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't solve it... my way to fix it was deleting the project and starting it again... and now it works, don't know what was wrong.